# Process_Exporter fails to find the single process I'm interested in

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-process-exporter

I'm using process_exporter for Prometheus but it does for some reason fail to find the single process I'm looking for.

The process in question is last in a chain of X parent processes

The process shows up fine in "top"
Listing /proc shows 124 running processes and there seems to be nothing special about the process in question. the /proc/pid/stat shows the "comm" name as value #1 (QtDisp) as expected.

Running prometheus_exporter with -debug and grep:ing for "found new proc" clearly shows that it only finds 123 out of the 124 processes running, the one missing is the one I'm looking for!

If I restart the process I'm interested in monitoring from commandline, and then restart process_exporter, then it finds it. This is unfortunately not a valid workaround for me.

Update:
During startup, starting process_exporter before the process of interest seems to catch it for a brief time, then "loosing track" of it.

Any ideas?

/K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in a by process exporter used library(prometheus/procfs) which is now fixed:
https://github.com/ncabatoff/process-exporter/issues/89